# Internal server error in flask application when I try to import pandas

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I'm trying to import pandas in my flask application. The moment I do that, I get an internal server error. I'm running my application on a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 20.0.4).

Server: nginx

Everything runs as expected if I don't import pandas. I have installed pandas through pip install already.Request you to assist me with this :)

Here's the snippet:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")
import pandas as pd


@app.route("/")
def home():
    try: 
        return render_template('home.html')
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Could you run the app on debug mode, ```app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)``` and post the error msg here.

Comment: Hi Manu. I tried this but not getting any error log. When I run the python file, I don't face any issues. It is only when I access the app on the website I get internal server error.

Comment: When you are getting the internal server error, what is the output at the terminal?

Comment: It is just blank. Stays on the last line i.e., Debug PIN: 123-456

Comment: Can you import pandas in a separate .py file? Say a one-liner ```import pandas```

Comment: I can import pandas in a separate .py file. However, when I try to import this py file in my main flask file, I still get same error. I need to use pandas to extract some data from an excel file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240636/discussion-between-manu-s-pillai-and-rakesh-v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240636/discussion-between-manu-s-pillai-and-rakesh-v), you have to import the packages inside the `if` block, like this.

```py
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pandas as pd
    ...
```

I may only guess with the limited information that this works because of how the default *development* server works in flask. Some of the time the routing of each request is handled by a new spawned/forked process, when the system is something that is resource constrained, importing heavy packages on all the processes may end up taking up the resource limit and hence killing the process or the applet rendering server error.

Glad this helped.